# Replacing SP & DP in Android

Tags: android

I recently started a project with a friend when we were developing the app I came to know that it better to use SP for text size so I told him to change all text sizes from DP to SP but instead of changing only for text sizes, he changed for all of them including layouts.

Problem: only changing Layouts back to DP instead of SP & change only the text sizes from DP to SP.

Note: Undo doesn't works. My project have lots of files so it's extremely difficult for me to find each & every instance manually.

Tried using find & replace but couldn't find a way to exclude specific tags.

Comment: This is why you use source control.  Put your code on github.  It's free, and PRs serve as a record of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use Android Studio (Intelij IDEA) refactoring possibilities. You can find and replace entries all over the project. You can use Ctrl + Shift + R hotkey (macOS: Cmd + Shift + R) which will open the window where you can specify the entry you want to replace and value for it.

Comment: Yes I know that, & I tried that it but is there any way to filter it to only show non text size tags.

Comment: You may try to use regex in search line